# Solve quartic equation $a^4-6a^2b-8ac-3b^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quartics

Please help me to find roots of this quartic equation for `a`:
$$a^4-6a^2b-8ac-3b^2=0$$

Wolfram Alpha gave this [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:a%5E4-6*a%5E2*b-8*a*c-3*b%5E2%2F%2F%5D%7D,+%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:a%2F%2F%5D%7D%5D).

But may be there is simple way to get all `a`?

Comment: i think no you can calculate this solution per hand

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html) is of some help?

Comment: The $c$ seems to be really odd

Comment: I cannot come up with any beautiful trick, but maybe you could use the standard "Quartic Formula" (http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac12/fac12.html)

Comment: Are the variables supposed to be integers?  Then there are simplifications based on divisibility.  Otherwise, why should it be at all simple?

Comment: Then for example $a$ and $b$ are the same parity and $a(a^3-8c)$ must be a multiple of $3$, so either $a$ is a multiple of $3$ or $a \equiv c \pmod 3$  Also if you solve for $c$ you find $\frac {3b^2}a$ is an integer

Comment: You can factor the polynomial as $(a^2+pa+q)(a^2-pa+r)$ and identify the coefficients. Then by eliminating $r,q$, you get an equation that is cubic in $p^2$. Now there is no shortcut, you need the general formulas for the cubic, but it suffices to compute a positive root. Finally, from the factorization, you have two quadratics to solve. The complete formulas aren't any simpler, but the whole computation is eased by using intermediate quantities.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the equation by completing the squares
\begin{align}
a^4-6a^2b-8ac-3b^2
=(a^2+s)^2 -( 2s+6b)\left( a +\frac{4c}{2s+6b} \right)^2\tag1\\
\end{align}
where $s$ happens to satisfy $(s+b)^3=8(c^2-b^3)$, or
$s=2\sqrt[3]{c^2-b^3}-b$.
For notational convenience, denote
$$p=\frac12\sqrt{2s+6b}= \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{c^2-b^3}+b }\tag2$$
and then $s=2p^2-3b$.
Substitute them into (1) and then factorize to get
$$\left(a^2+2pa+2p^2-3b-\frac{2c}p\right) \left(a^2-2pa+2p^2-3b+\frac{2c}p\right)=0
$$
which yields the solutions
$$a=p\pm \sqrt{ 3b-p^2+\frac{2c}p },\>\>\> -p\pm \sqrt{ 3b-p^2-\frac{2c}p } $$
with $p$ given by (2).

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Given}\quad a^4-6a^2b-8ac-3b^2=0\quad\implies 3b^2+6a^2b -(a^4-8ac)=0$$

The solution for  $b$ using the quadratic equation is
$$b = \pm\frac{2 \sqrt{a^4 - 2 a c}}{\sqrt{3}} - a^2\quad\text{for}\quad a\in\mathbb{R}\land c\in\mathbb{R}\land b\in\mathbb{R}\iff a^4-2ac\ge0$$
Technically, this defines all values of $a$ but perhaps you seek integers.

Regular algebras solves for $c$ as $$c = \frac{a^4 - 6 a^2 b - 3 b^2}{8 a}$$
The second equation looks easier to work with (though you can try the first if you want) and experimentation in a spreadsheet offers these sample integer triples.
\begin{equation}
(1,-11,-37)\quad
(1,-7,-13)\quad
(1,-3,-1)\quad
(1,1,-1)\quad
(1,5,-13)\quad
(1,9,-37)\quad\\
(2,-8,1)\quad
(2,-4,4)\quad
(2,0,1)\quad
(2,4,-8)\quad
(2,8,-23)\quad
(2,12,-44)\quad\\
(3,-11,13)\quad
(3,-7,13)\quad
(3,-3,9)\quad
(3,1,1)\quad
(3,5,-11)\quad
(3,9,-27)\quad
(3,13,-47)\quad\\
(4,-8,26)\quad
(4,0,8)\quad
(4,8,-22)\quad\\
(5,5,-5)\quad\\
(6,-8,59)\quad
(6,-4,44)\quad
(6,0,27)\quad
(6,4,8)\quad
(6,8,-13)\quad
(6,12,-36)\quad\\
(7,-7,77)\quad\\
(8,-8,109)\quad
(8,0,64)\quad
(8,8,13)\quad
\end{equation}

WolframAlpha offer only the roots $a=0,b=0$ or
$a\ne0\land c = \frac{a^4 - 6 a^2 b - 3 b^2}{8 a}$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+roots+a%5E4-6a%5E2b-8ac-3b%5E2%3D0++). This solution for $c$ (as I pointed out above) appears to have infinite integer solutions and, when $a=1$, it appears that these have a symmetry for values of $b$ around zero. Let me know if you have other questions about this.